# Sitemap generator script for photos

Tags: php, sitemap, photos

I'm working on a sitemap script but now I need to know how I can scan all my photo's since they are in different folders (I'm working with albums)
All my images that I want to get into the sitemap are in this directory: public_html/Albums/{Albumname}/{photo name}

How can I do this?

Comment: By using `opendir` and `readdir` recursively.

Comment: Have you stored your images in a database? Do you want to read them from the disk or from a remote source like a CDN? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the location in not remote then you can try the following:

```
<?php
$path = realpath('public_html/Albums');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $filename)
{
        echo "$filename\n";
}
?>
```

You can generate the URL accordingly in the loop.

Comment: Now I get the full path to the file but I would like the filename, is that possible?

Comment: explode with the separator and get the last index of the exploded array.

Comment: My script is working now, thanks for your help!